# How to find the radix (base) of a number given its representation in another radix (base)?

Tags: number-systems

What's the method to find the base of any given number?

E.g. find $r$ such that $(121)_r=(144)_8$, where $r$ and $8$ are the bases.

So how do I find the value of $r$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By definition $$144_8=1\cdot8^2+4\cdot8^1+4\cdot8^0=64+32+4=100\;,$$ and $$121_r=1\cdot r^2+2\cdot r^1+1\cdot r^0=r^2+2r+1\;.$$ To find $r$, just solve the quadratic equation $$r^2+2r+1=100$$ by whatever method you find most convenient; the slickest method is probably to notice that $r^2+2r+1=(r+1)^2$, so $(r+1)^2=100=10^2$.

Comment: So value of r here would be i guess, 9 ? (r+1)^2= 100    -> r+1 = 10     -> r = 10-1      -> r =9

Comment: @Kishan: That’s right. And you can now check: $$121_9=1\cdot9^2+2\cdot9^1+1\cdot9^0=81+18+1=100\;.$$

Comment: This doesn't uniquely describe the base though, we can also have $r+1 = -10$, which implies $r = -11$ which also works, and there's nothing saying a base has to be positive

Answer (score 5):

remember the bold letters are the powers

---

(121)**r**=(144)**8**

---

Now r and 8 is the base so,

$1\cdot r^2+2 \cdot r^1+1\cdot r^0 = 1 \cdot 8^2+4\cdot 8^1+4 \cdot 8^0$

---

$r^2+2r+1=64+32+4$

---

$r^2+2r+1=100$

---

$(r+1)² =100$

---

$r+1=10$

---

$r= 10-1$

---

$r=9$

Comment: Essentially the same as Brian's answer, but hey, welcome to this site! You may want to learn how to format your equations, and avoid posting duplicate answers in the future.

Answer (score 2):

First let's find what 144(8) equals, with "8" as the base
Listing the digits in order, count them off from the right, starting with zero:

digits:     1  4  4
numbering:      2  1  0

Then the bottom row of numbers become the assigned exponential numbers, and so we have: 
144= 1⋅8ˆ2 + 4⋅8ˆ1 + 4⋅8ˆ0 = 64 + 32 + 4 = 100

As for 121(r), with "r" as the base, we can again list off the digits in order, counting them off from the right starting with zero:

digits:         1  2  1
numbering:      2  1  0

Again, the bottom row of numbers become the assigned exponential numbers, and so we have:
121r= 1⋅rˆ2 + 2⋅rˆ1 + 1⋅rˆ0 = rˆ2 + 2r + 1

We can then find "r" by solving the quadratic equation that we have now created:
rˆ2 + 2r + 1 = 100                            equation
(r + 1)ˆ2 = 100 = 10ˆ2                        factor (r + 1)
± r + 1 = ± 10                                use the square root property
± r = ± 10 - 1                                isolate the "r"
r = 9                                         solve for r

HOPE THIS HELPS!!! JUST CLARIFICATION OF ALL THE STEPS SO IT APPEARS LONGER THAN APPRECIATED :D

Comment: for clarification