# What is the radix (base) of number $(9)_r$ if its decimal representation is $(21)_{10}$?

Tags: number-systems

I want to find $r$. The method that I followed is:

$(9\times r^0) = (2\times 10^1) + (1\times 10^0)$

which gives no solution.

Comment: Based on [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/217361/307169) it sounds to me like "no solution" is correct, although I don't have the time right now to think about it more thoroughly.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is stated correctly? Seems to me that $(9)_r$ is the number $9$ no matter what $r$ is, and that certainly isn't $21$. There is no radix that will make these values equal. You are right in saying that there is no solution to the problem as stated.

Comment: Maybe it's meant that $(9)_{10} = (21)_4$, that would at least make sense. It would answer in what radix, the number 9 has the representation "21"

Comment: @MPW Yes, the problem is stated correctly. Actually my birthday cake could only hold 9 candles but I am 21, so I wanted to find a base for 9 that would justify this.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thanks for your comment but the problem is stated correctly.

Comment: @ahsan. If a radix is $\le 9$, $9$ makes no sense as a number. If the radix is $> 9$, $9$ is just the same as decimal $9$, so it cannot be done.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma ahhh makes sense. Thankyou!

Comment: Also, the number of candles is just the number of candles (i.e. the cardinality of that set), it has no radix. A **string representation** does have a radix. So the idea is ill-posed.